# Update value using row index

Tags: sql

Say I have a table like below with values I want to update in specific rows, but no primary key, I only know the index of the row I want to update. Is this possible with generic SQL or would I need some DB specific tools? I'm using Postgres and SQLite. I realise this is bad DB design and the obvious solution is to simply add an id primary key to the table, but my use case is the DB is the backend for a flexible Excel-like application, where I have no control over the table schema, as it is user defined.

```sql
CREATE TABLE fruits (name TEXT);
INSERT INTO fruits VALUES (banana) (aple) (orange);
```

To fix the typo, I want to do something like:

```sql
UPDATE fruits SET name = 'apple' WHERE *row index* = 1;
```

Note I'm using 0-indexing in this pseudo code example.

Comment: You can't. (without adding an id column to the table.)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try
`UPDATE fruits SET name='<new_name>' WHERE rowid=3` ?

[rowid docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Comment: Is this specific to SQLite? I'm looking for a generic SQL solution if possible.

Comment: Indeed specific to SQLite, there is no such standard, every DB has its own specific  identifiers for that ( if at all ). But as you said, simplest solution would be just add an id column and update the row through this id.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
UPDATE fruits SET name = 'apple' WHERE name =(
    SELECT name FROM
       (SELECT name, row_number() over (order by name) as line_number FROM fruits )
    A 
    WHERE line_number = 1
)
```

So `ROW_NUMBER` is dynamically creating a unique number for each name, but it is doing so by sorting the results by name. So the index will be 1 if you want to select the 'Aple' entry.